# jupyer lab browser right click shows chrome menu, macbook

Tags: jupyter-lab

[image: when I right clicked on jupyter lab in chrome]

when I right click the file on jupyterlab browser, I expect the menu for copy, cut, duplicates... but it is not right now. I updated the jupyter-lab and used safari instead of, but it doesn't work..

Anyone experienced this? I use macbook air 2018, catalina

Comment: Have you tried a different Internet browser? In your current browser, could you try to disable any addons you have?

Comment: @krassowski Thanks! I just make the addons stop, so it works :)

Comment: which addons did you stop to make it work? In which browser is it working now?